# DRF canned filter - best practice?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use Django REST Framework in my Django app to provide an API, and have recently added filtering. To support a couple of things in the UI, I'd like to be able to provide some canned/named filter presets - for example, there's a `/api/tasks` viewset that gives you a list of all the tasks. Tasks have a completed status field and a completion date. In the UI, I'd like to be able to fetch a list of all tasks that are either incomplete, or completed but within the last couple of hours. This is easy enough with Django querysets but not with the DRF filters - the final goal would be to be able to fetch `/api/tasks?recent` or something similar.

Is there a best practice for doing this kind of thing? I can create a new ViewSet with a different queryset field, but is there a nicer way?

Edit: Here's my current solution:

```
class PushTaskViewSet(AuthenticatedAPIModelViewSet):
    queryset = PushTask.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PushTaskSerializer       
    filter_fields = ('complete', 'date_created', 'date_completed', 'progress')

class RecentPushTaskViewSet(AuthenticatedAPIModelViewSet):
    # Get all tasks which are either incomplete, or only recently completed
    serializer_class = PushTaskSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return PushTask.objects.filter(Q(complete=False) | Q(date_completed__gt=self.get_completed_threshold()))

    def get_completed_threshold(self):
        return datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc) - timedelta(hours=4)

router.register(r'master-tasks', viewsets.PushTaskViewSet)
router.register(r'recent-master-tasks', viewsets.RecentPushTaskViewSet, base_name="recent-master-tasks")
```

which does work, but just feels clunky.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **DjangoFilterBackend**. For detailed information, see the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend).
After installation `django-filter` lib don't forget to add **DjangoFilterBackend** in the `settings.py` file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
     )
}
```

and then use it in the view:

```
class TaskListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('status', )
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

Alternative way to filter objects is use [Filtering against query parameters](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters). For this just to override get_queryset method:

```
class TaskListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Task.objects.all()
        status = self.request.query_params.get('status', None)
        if status:
            queryset = queryset.filter(status=status)
        return queryset
```

Comment: That's true (and what I said in the question), but as far as I can see it doesn't support OR, and also I was looking to have something simpler for the common cases.

Comment: @ AnotherHowie I expanded my answer